# Get full width of element with Angular 5

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

How to get the full width of an element with angular 5, not only the computed with? Right now i only get the width of the client and not the full width of the element.

What's wrong with this code?

```
 @ViewChild('box') box: ElementRef;
 ...
 this.boxWidth = this.box.nativeElement.clientWidth;
```

HTML

```
 <ion-row nowrap class="time-bar" [ngStyle]="{'left': leftscroll}" #box>
   <p *ngFor="let i of day">{{i}}</p>
 </ion-row>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use offsetWidth. It will also includes border  width

```
@ViewChild('box') box: ElementRef;
 this.boxWidth = this.box.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
```